# Return the size of the hash table?

Tags: c++, vector, size, hashtable

*Excuse me in advance if I'm not explaining this clear..*
Okay so I have declared a hash table using a vector like so:

```
> class HashTable{

    private:
        vector<string> arrayofbuckets[100];

    public:
         void insertelement(string input);
         void deleteelement(string remove);
         bool lookupelement(string search);
         int tablesize();

> }; // end of class
```

I have also creating a menu using a switch statement to insert elements into the hash table:

```
> case 'I':
{
        cout << " Which element would you like to insert?: ";
        cin >> Element;

        hash.insertelement(Element);

        }
    break;
```

It then gets passed on to this function:

```
void HashTable::insertelement(string input){

    int hashValue = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<input.length(); i++){

        hashValue = hashValue + int(input[i]);

    }

    hashValue = hashValue % 100;
    arrayofbuckets[hashValue].push_back(input);

    cout << " The element " << input << " has been put into value " << hashValue << ends;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to write a function to obtain and display the size of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to keep track of the size inside functions that should initialise or modify it:

```
HashTable::HashTable() : size_(0) { }

void HashTable::insertelement(string input){
    ...do all the existing stuff...
    ++size_;
}

// similarly --size_ inside deleteelement...

int HashTable::tablesize() const { return size_; }
```

Make sure you add an `int size_;` data member.

Do note that `bool lookupelement(string search) const;` and `int tablesize() const;` should be `const` - I've inserted the keyword here so you know where to put it, and used it above when defining `tablesize()`.

---

If you were ***really*** determined to avoid an extra member variable, you could also do this...

```
int HashTable::tablesize() const {
    int size = 0;
    for (std::vector<std::string>& vs : arrayOfBuckets)
        size += vs.size();
    return size;
}
```

...but most users will expect a constant-time and fast `size()` function: they may call it every time through their loops, so keep it cheap.

Comment: You sir, have just saved me from stressing over this uni assignment. Thank you!

Comment: @JoeDavis: you're welcome - good luck with your course.  Cheers.  (Small tip - if you'd tagged this with C++ you'd probably have got more help and faster)